# Can anyone figure out what is wrong with my syntax in this code?

Tags: vb.net, oledb

"Here's the code. I keep getting an exception when I try to insert. It says.. Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Mary','Smith','Jane','2 oak','Cincinnati','OH','45220','413-3222','15'."

```
    mySQL = "Insert into Team
              ([Player Number],
               [First Name], 
               [Last Name], 
               [Parent Name], 
               [Address] , 
               [City], 
               [State], 
               [Zip Code], 
               [Telephone Number], 
               [Age]) 
          values (" _
               & intPlayerNo & "," _
               & strFirstName & "','" _
               & strLastName & "','" _
               & strParentName & "','" _
               & strAddress & "','" _
               & strCity & "','" _
               & strState & "','" _
               & strZipCode & "','" _
               & strPhone & "','" _
               & intAge & ")"
```

Comment: Why not try and print the string to your screen before sending it to the database? That way, you could spot errors such as the missing `'` before your first string element.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather wrong way of building an sql query. You want to use parameters in your query

```
mySQL = "Insert into Team([Player Number]) values (@playerNumber)"
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
Dim command As New SqlCommand(mySQL, connection)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playerNumber", intPlayerNo)
```

And so on. If you don't do this you leave yourself open to all sorts of nastiness like sql injections not to mention that it's prone to typing errors as you already encountered.

Comment: STRONG emphasis on exposure to SQL-Injection and ALWAYS parameterize it.  Good example with parameterization.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a single quote before strFirstname. Should be

```
& intPlayerNo & ",'" _
& strFirstName & "','" _
```

And you should remove the last single quote before intAge, so it should be:

```
& strPhone & "'," _
& intAge & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mySQL = "Insert into Team([Player Number], [First Name], [Last Name], [Parent Name], [Address] , [City], [State], [Zip Code], [Telephone Number], [Age]) values (" _
           & intPlayerNo & ",'" _
           & strFirstName & "','" _
           & strLastName & "','" _
           & strParentName & "','" _
           & strAddress & "','" _
           & strCity & "','" _
           & strState & "','" _
           & strZipCode & "','" _
           & strPhone & "'," _
           & intAge & ")"
```

Missed two `'`'s it looked like.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it had something to do with a quote.

Comment: @RamziMuasher - These kinds of errors are common when you construct SQL queries the wrong way.  You should be using parameterized queries instead and then you would have had this error plus you will avoid a serious security problem.

Comment: This is actually the method we were taught by our instructor. Where would I learn about parameterized queries? Can you suggest any resources? Thanks.